# Once and for all: `programIdIndex` is 0 based, right?

Tags: solana

Given an array of accounts of length 5 in a transaction like so:

```
   "accountKeys": [
         "3hyA2VoeXrMwfxU5AvD9FS2auvHL9wNHLacKkkSVEzPf",  # PidIndex 0
         "6bMbqts34vu4GKbFUUs51h8BskjFK26WvsZiimc2B7bf",  # PidIndex 1
         "SysvarS1otHashes111111111111111111111111111",   # PidIndex 2
         "SysvarC1ock11111111111111111111111111111111",   # PidIndex 3
         "Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111"    # PidIndex 4
                    ],
```

The following instruction will be processed by the `Vote` program(not `SysvarClock`):

```
"accounts": [1,2,3,0],
"data":"rTmw9...nXy",
"programIdIndex": 4
}
```

Correct?

Comment: Yep that's correct, did anything make you think otherwise?

Comment: Was going through a block and couldn't find any `"programIdIndex": 0` probably.. thanks for chiming in!